# Improve Query Performance, Adding where clause grids query to a halt

Tags: sql, intersystems-cache

Running the following SQL results in a query that runs in around 0.338s

adding a where clause and query times out. All I want to achieve is a list of test results for a particular test_code

Result_Set will have many Test_Results on the index Result_Set_Row_ID
Date_Received_Index will have many Result_Sets on the index Result_Set_Row_ID

I have tried altering the order of JOINS, adding clauses to the join statements.

```
SELECT 
              Date_Received_Index.Registration_Number,
              Date_Received_Index.Specimen_Number,
              Result,
              Result_Comment,
              Result_Comment_Exp ,
              Result_Exp,
              Short_Exp,
              Test_Code,
              Test_Exp,
              Test_Row_ID,
              Units,
              Result_Set.Set_Code ,
              Result_Set.Date_Time_Authorised,
              Result_Set.Date_Booked_In ,
              Date_Received_Index.Discipline,
              Date_Received_Index.Namespace
FROM         
              Result_Set
              INNER JOIN Test_Result ON Result_Set.Result_Set_Row_ID = Test_Result.Result_Set_Row_ID
              INNER JOIN Date_Received_Index ON (Date_Received_Index.Request_Row_ID = Result_Set.Request_Row_ID)

WHERE         
              DATEDIFF('D', Date_Received_Index.Date_Received, current_timestamp) < 1 AND
              Date_Received_Index.Namespace = 'CHM'
```

adding a WHERE clause e.g.

```
          DATEDIFF('D', Date_Received_Index.Date_Received, current_timestamp) < 1 AND
          Date_Received_Index.Namespace = 'CHM' 
     AND Test_Code = 'K'
```

results in the query timing out

I would like to be able to construct an SQL statement that is performant and just selects the test_code specified in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

This comes down to the Query Plan.  Can you share the query plan?
My suspicion is that the column Test_Code is not indexed and the addition to the WHERE clause is causing the optimizer to select the wrong query plan.

I think the SQL optimizer is not able to optimize the portion
DATEDIFF('D', Date_Received_Index.Date_Received, current_timestamp) < 1

without knowing your schema my question would be of the three columns used in the where clause Date_Received_Index.Date_Received,  Date_Received_Index.Namespace, and Test_Code are any of these columns index.  You already indicated Test_Code is not.

Depending on what version of Cache you are using you might try

```
SELECT 
Date_Received_Index.Registration_Number,
Date_Received_Index.Specimen_Number,
Result,
Result_Comment,
Result_Comment_Exp ,
Result_Exp,
Short_Exp,
Test_Code,
Test_Exp,
Test_Row_ID,
Units,
Result_Set.Set_Code ,
Result_Set.Date_Time_Authorised,
Result_Set.Date_Booked_In ,
Date_Received_Index.Discipline,
Date_Received_Index.Namespace
FROM     %PARALLEL
Result_Set
INNER JOIN Test_Result ON Result_Set.Result_Set_Row_ID = Test_Result.Result_Set_Row_ID
INNER JOIN Date_Received_Index ON (Date_Received_Index.Request_Row_ID = Result_Set.Request_Row_ID)

WHERE         
DATEDIFF('D', Date_Received_Index.Date_Received, current_timestamp) < 1
AND Date_Received_Index.Namespace = 'CHM' 
AND Test_Code = 'K'
```

Use of %PARALLEL can cause the query to be run using multiple threads.  If the server has a large number of CPUs it may run faster even if it's not optimized.

Comment: Thanks, at the moment, I only have access to the SQL interface. I can confirm that the Test_Code field does not appear to be indexed as far as I can see. I will see if I can get more data from the sys admins